# What is the fate of Australia (and Antarctica) in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I was just watching *Star Trek: The Next Generation* recently and my mind drifted to Australia.

I am aware that the political makeup of the planet has changed dramatically, with Africa becoming the *'United States of Africa'*, and so forth. So what has happened to Australia and Antarctica. Have they been assimilated by other pan-continent groupings?

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant "countries" instead of continents?

Comment: I think it's clear from context that the question is about politics rather than geography.

Comment: First of all, I did mean continents. As far as I'm concerned, both are continents. As Gaultheria stated, I am referring to politics.

Comment: If you're referring to politics, you aren't talking about continents. Continents are not political areas, they are geographical areas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Political

Australia was a separate political entity as of [2118](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:Earth_political_map.jpg) and we learn in [TNG: Attached](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Attached_(episode)) that Australia became part of United Earth in the mid-2100s

> **BEVERLY:** *Think about Earth -- what if one of the old nation-states, say Australia, had decided not to join the World
>   Government in twenty-one fifty? Would that have disqualified us from
>   being a Federation member?*

### Physical

Australia and Antarctica are exactly where you'd expect them to be and appear to be unscathed by the Great Atomic War, at least in the sort of detail you can see from space.

Comment: “what if one of the old nation-states, say Australia, had decided not to join the World Government in twenty-one fifty?” — Say *Australia*, Beverly? Come on — if anyone decides to hold out, it’ll be the bloody poms.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite No, we would join, demand concessions and then leave.

Comment: And Antarctica, which was never a country to begin with, presumably fell under the jurisdiction of "world government" (being a part of the world).